# R Markdown Pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

Whenever I do try to use R Markdown, and later on knit to pdf I get this error message:

> pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found

Is there any way to correct it? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to give more details on how you are doing what you are doing.

Comment: I would suggest using Rstudio, pandoc should work out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

You may not have pandoc installed, if you are on a linux I suggest that you use your package manager to install pandoc.

I was having this same problem on my Linux distribution, Manjaro, and it worked out fine.

Cheers!